# Running a simple command in my container causes the container to CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a simple command in my wildfly container. Its pwd - present working directory. When I am deploying the container and checking the log, it give the value of pwd. But the deployment itself throws CrashLoopBackOff and never recovers.

My yaml file -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wildfly
  labels:
    app: wildfly
spec:
  containers:
    - name: wildfly
      image: wildfly:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
         - name: wildfly-persistant-storage
           mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly
      command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'pwd']
  volumes:
    - name: wildfly-persistant-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: wildfly
```

When I deploy this file without the command, then the deployment succeeds and a default application runs at por 8080.
But with the command, the container always goes into CrashLoopBackOff.

Answer (score 0):

The normal expectation for a Kubernetes Deployment is that its container will never exit.  Imagine you're running some long-running process like, say, a Wildfly server; that will normally keep running and handling requests.  If it ever exits on its own, that suggests a problem and it needs to be restarted; if it restarts too frequently (it is in a "crash loop"), Kubernetes starts inserting a delay between restarts ("back-off") to reduce load and hope other components recover.

In your case, though, you're overriding the `command:` the container runs.  The `command:` runs *instead of* the normal command in the image (the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`).

So in this setup, you're running `pwd` instead of the Wildfly server.  `pwd` exits immediately, so Kubernetes restarts the container, and `pwd` exits immediately instead.  After this happens a couple of times, the pod goes into CrashLoopBackOff state.

You can solve this by just deleting the `command:` line to use the default command as described in the image.  If you need to debug the image in some way, consider using Docker tools to run a local temporary container, rather than trying to set up something in the cluster that isn't really running anything.